# path.join for the tmpDir returns two extra tokens (empty strings)

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

Code:

```
var tmp = path.join(os.tmpDir(), dir);
var segments = tmp.split(path.sep); // create directories/subdirectories
console.log(tmp);
for(var i=0; i<segments.length; i++) {
    var segment = segments.slice(0, i).join(path.sep);
    console.log(i, segment.length, segment, fs.existsSync(segment));
}
```

Output:

```
/var/folders/ch/pc8wsx1x1_v10hdl7zxnvjqr0000gn/T/somedir
0 0 '' false
1 0 '' false
2 4 '/var' true
3 12 '/var/folders' true
```

Question:

Why index 0 and 1 are empty strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of `segments.slice(0, i)`

The first iteration, it excludes the first element:

"slice extracts up to but not including end"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

The second iteration, it includes the first element, which is empty because of how the path was split: `tmp.split(path.sep)`, and since the path starts with a leading slash.

If you know it's always an absolute path, then start the loop at i=2. If a relative path might be inputted, you'll just have to start at i=1, and deal with the blank element at index 0 when working with absolute paths.